# May I ask a question which relates to commercial tools?

Tags: support, questions, scope

I want to make an automatic refactoring of source code. I can do it using regular expressions, code it in C# or writing a plugin for [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper).

The benefit of the last choice is that it would be code aware. It doesn't see the code as a long string, but it is aware of properties, fields, accessors, and so on.

Would a similar question fit Stack Overflow?

Comment: Questions about particular programming related tools are on-topic. I'm pretty sure there's even a tag for resharper.

Comment: Assuming ReSharper has an public API which you use to achieve whatever programming task you're after, questions about the usage or failures with that API are on-topic. It still requires you include what you tried, which input you gave, which output was the result, etc. Asking us to build you a refactor plugin for reSharper is too broad and will be closed as such.

Comment: It's off topic because you're asking for opinions.  Also, you should create a code fix, anyhow. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix